# Preventing hens from eating plants

Tags: safety, birds, plants

My neighbor's hens always nibble of our flowering plants and herbs. We've tried fencing and everything yet they still somehow manage to get to the plants. Is there some way to prevent them from eating the plants? A repellent or something that would work?

Comment: Are the hens fenced or walking around freely? If they are fenced, do they escape or just put their heads through the fence to peck at your flowers?

Comment: @Elmy they are free, so they just hop over to our side

Comment: What kind of fencing did you try? They generally can't get over high ones.

Comment: @AllisonC I'm not so sure.. I think I saw a [documentary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_Run) once that implied they might have their ways :D

Comment: @motosubatsu I've seen that documentary. :) It depends a bit also on what kind of bird the neighbor has. We kept our chickens in a covered pen (more to keep the cats out than the birds in), but our turkeys were in an open-topped pen with high walls and couldn't fly or jump out.

Comment: @motosubatsu the link opens up to a cartoon's wiki page

Comment: @BellaSwan Apologies.. just a little humor.

Comment: @motosubatsu Oh, i missed the laughing emoticon on your comment, I guess :D

Answer (score 2):

There is a little trick that helps push hens. You can sprinkle the soil and your plants with spices because the spices have a strong smell that can keep hens away. You can make a spice mixture with curry, cinnamon, paprika, black pepper and salt. Garlic powder can also be effective.
Another method can also work it consists of spreading lemon peel or even whole piece of lemon on the ground near your plants.